# Rails for loop exiting after first iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I have a `for` loop that is supposed to loop through an object's keys and I've noticed that it seems to exit on the first iteration.  My controller initializes my service with the current date and calls `parse_leads`.  `parse_leads` then calls `grouped_leads_by_location` and starts looping through the returned object.  This loop is the one that seems to exit on first iteration.

```
# Controller
def generate_invite_texts
        params[:signature] == ENV['TEMPORIZE_KEY'] ? valid =  true : valid = false

        if valid
            p "Valid: generate invite texts, #{Time.current.in_time_zone('America/New_York')}"
            SakariService.new(Time.current.in_time_zone('America/New_York').to_date).parse_leads
        else
            p "invalid key: generate invite texts"
        end

        head :ok
end

# SakariService.rb
class SakariService
    include HTTParty
    attr_reader :date
    base_uri 'https://api.sakari.io'

    def initialize(date, no_auth = false)
        @options = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            }
        }
        @attempts = 0
        @date = date.to_date.end_of_day
        @potential_clients = PotentialClient.date_filter(@date.beginning_of_day, @date.end_of_day)
    end



    # ******************************************************************
    # Begin functionality for scheduling the texts to be sent
    # ******************************************************************
    def parse_leads
        grouped_leads_by_location.keys.each do |location_id|
            p "LocationID: #{location_id}"
            send_text_at = calc_send_time(location_id)
            p "Send text at: #{send_text_at}"
            schedule_text(send_text_at, location_id) if send_text_at.present?
        end
    end


    # Adds two business days and 2 hours to date
    def calc_send_time(location_id)
        start_date_range = Date.current + 2.days
        end_date_range = start_date_range + 4.days
        date_range = ( start_date_range .. end_date_range )
        location = Location.find(location_id)

        p "start: #{start_date_range}"
        p "end: #{end_date_range}"
        p "range: #{date_range}"

        date_range.each do |possible_date|
            p "testing: #{possible_date}"
            if !is_weekend?(possible_date) and !Location.is_holiday?(possible_date) and location.is_open_by_date?(possible_date)
                time = location.get_open_time(possible_date) + 2.hours
                send_text_at = Time.zone.parse("#{possible_date.strftime("%F")} #{time.strftime("%T")}")
                return send_text_at
                break
            end
        end

        return nil
    end

    def grouped_leads_by_location
      grouped_leads = @potential_clients \
        .group_by { |pc| pc.location_id } \
        .keep_if { |k, v| !k.nil? }

        # outputs something like:  { "1" => [#<PotentialClient:0x00000006cb1910> {...}, ...], "2" => [#<PotentialClient:0x00000006cb1910> {...}, ...]}
    end

    def schedule_text(datetime, location_id)
        p "scheduling text: #{location_id} - #{datetime}"
        datetime = datetime.to_datetime
        SakariTextWorker.perform_at(datetime, @date, location_id)
    end
end
```

In my logs I see the following:

```
"Valid: generate invite texts, 2020-04-11"
"potential_clients"
D, [2020-04-11T04:56:02.562327 #4] DEBUG -- : [7b48a6db-0d4c-4dd2-9ed5-d436eab62e57]   PotentialClient Load (5.7ms)  SELECT "potential_clients".* FROM "potential_clients" WHERE (potential_clients.created_at >= '2020-04-11 04:00:00' and potential_clients.created_at <= '2020-04-12 03:59:59.999999')
"LocationID: 40"
D, [2020-04-11T04:56:02.564703 #4] DEBUG -- : [7b48a6db-0d4c-4dd2-9ed5-d436eab62e57]   Location Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 40], ["LIMIT", 1]]
"start: 2020-04-13"
"end: 2020-04-17"
"range: 2020-04-13..2020-04-17"
"testing: 2020-04-13"
"Send text at: 2020-04-13 11:00:00 -0400"
"scheduling text: 40 - 2020-04-13 11:00:00 -0400"
```

As you can see the loop runs for `location_id` 40 and then never continues.  After re-running the query, `grouped_leads_by_location.keys` returns  `["40", "3", "42", "75", "1", "5", "2"]` so it should have continued.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: When you say "loop runs for location_id 40 and then never continues", does the controller action complete? I am wondering if "        SakariTextWorker.perform_at(datetime, @date, location_id)" is asynchronous or it is preventing the action from completing.

Comment: As you can see in the logs, only the first key in `grouped_leads_by_location.keys` is printed.  The loop never continues to the next

Comment: Does the controller action return with head :ok ?

Comment: It ended up being a timezone related bug -_- .  I appreciate the help